# Implement IntoIterator for binary tree

Tags: oop, iterator, rust, traits, lifetime-scoping

I am trying to build a binary tree and write an iterator to traverse values in the tree.
When implementing the IntoIterator trait for my tree nodes I ran into a problem with lifetimes

```
src\main.rs:43:6: 43:8 error: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates [E0207]
src\main.rs:43 impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for Node<T> {
```

I understand that I need to specify that NodeIterator will live as long as Node but I am unsure of how to express that

```
use std::cmp::PartialOrd;
use std::boxed::Box;

struct Node<T: PartialOrd> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct NodeIterator<'a, T: 'a + PartialOrd> {
    current: &'a Node<T>,
    parent: Option<&'a Node<T>>,
}

impl<T: PartialOrd> Node<T> {
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        ...
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for Node<T> { // line 43
     type Item = T;
     type IntoIter = NodeIterator<'a, T>;

     fn into_iter(&self) -> Self::IntoIter {
         NodeIterator::<'a> {
             current: Some(&self),
             parent: None
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You have a further problem: what is the parent of the parent? You'll need to keep a stack of references to nodes in the iterator if you don't have parent pointers in your tree.

Comment: @MatthieuM. the parent of a parent is None

Comment: Oh, wait now I see what you mean. Yes I'll need to track that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular error that you are getting is that `'a` should appear on the right of `for`. Otherwise, how could the compiler know what `a` is?

When implementing `IntoIterator` you have to decide whether the iterator will *consume* the container, or whether it'll just produce references into it. At the moment, your setup is inconsistent, and the error message points it out.

In the case of a binary tree, you also have to think about which order you want to produce the values in: traditional orders are depth first (yielding a sorted sequence) and breadth first (exposing the "layers" of the tree). I'll assume depth first as it's the most common one.

---

Let's tackle the case of a consuming iterator first. It's simpler in the sense that we don't have to worry about lifetimes.

```
#![feature(box_patterns)]

struct Node<T: PartialOrd> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct NodeIterator<T: PartialOrd> {
    stack: Vec<Node<T>>,
    next: Option<T>,
}

impl<T: PartialOrd> IntoIterator for Node<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = NodeIterator<T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let mut stack = Vec::new();

        let smallest = pop_smallest(self, &mut stack);

        NodeIterator { stack: stack, next: Some(smallest) }
    }
}

impl<T: PartialOrd> Iterator for NodeIterator<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if let Some(next) = self.next.take() {
            return Some(next);
        }

        if let Some(Node { value, right, .. }) = self.stack.pop() {
            if let Some(right) = right {
                let box right = right;
                self.stack.push(right);
            }
            return Some(value);
        }

        None
    }
}

fn pop_smallest<T: PartialOrd>(node: Node<T>, stack: &mut Vec<Node<T>>) -> T {
    let Node { value, left, right } = node;

    if let Some(left) = left {
        stack.push(Node { value: value, left: None, right: right });
        let box left = left;
        return pop_smallest(left, stack);
    }

    if let Some(right) = right {
        let box right = right;
        stack.push(right);
    }

    value
}

fn main() {
    let root = Node {
        value: 3,
        left: Some(Box::new(Node { value: 2, left: None, right: None })),
        right: Some(Box::new(Node { value: 4, left: None, right: None }))
    };

    for t in root {
        println!("{}", t);
    }
}
```

---

Now, we can "easily" adapt it to the non-consuming case by sprinkling in the appropriate references:

```
struct RefNodeIterator<'a, T: PartialOrd + 'a> {
    stack: Vec<&'a Node<T>>,
    next: Option<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T: PartialOrd + 'a> IntoIterator for &'a Node<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = RefNodeIterator<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let mut stack = Vec::new();

        let smallest = pop_smallest_ref(self, &mut stack);

        RefNodeIterator { stack: stack, next: Some(smallest) }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: PartialOrd + 'a> Iterator for RefNodeIterator<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        if let Some(next) = self.next.take() {
            return Some(next);
        }

        if let Some(node) = self.stack.pop() {
            if let Some(ref right) = node.right {
                self.stack.push(right);
            }
            return Some(&node.value);
        }

        None
    }
}

fn pop_smallest_ref<'a, T>(node: &'a Node<T>, stack: &mut Vec<&'a Node<T>>) -> &'a T
    where
        T: PartialOrd + 'a
{
    if let Some(ref left) = node.left {
        stack.push(node);
        return pop_smallest_ref(left, stack);
    }

    if let Some(ref right) = node.right {
        stack.push(right);
    }

    &node.value
}
```

There's a lot to unpack in there; so take your time to digest it. Specifically:

- the use of `ref` in `Some(ref right) = node.right` is because I don't want to consume `node.right`, only to obtain a reference inside the `Option`; the compiler will complain that I cannot move out of a borrowed object without it (so I just follow the complaints),
- in `stack.push(right)`, `right: &'a Box<Node<T>>` and yet `stack: Vec<&'a Node<T>>`; this is the magic of `Deref`: `Box<T>` implements `Deref<T>` so the compiler automatically transforms the reference as appropriate.

*Note: I didn't write this code as-is; instead I just put the first few references where I expect them to be (such as the return type of `Iterator`) and then let the compiler guide me.*

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware you could implement methods for a reference type. Could you point me to the documentation or explanation for rules of that, it doesn't seem to be explained in the methods chapter of the rust book

Comment: @SpencerKillen: Note that there are two forms of `impl`: inherent `impl` are about implementing methods for a struct or enum, whereas trait `impl` are about implementing a [trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html). It's the trait you can implement either for a type *or* a reference (mutable or not) to said type.